# Run a Node.JS in-memory script from Node JS code

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory, heap-memory, dump

I have 2 files , `app.js` and `performance.js`.

I want to put all the code of `performance.js` in memory , and whenever needed run
requests that reach to `app.js` against the code of `performance.js` **IN MEMORY**.

**Notice: I don't want to store a file in memory and then download it into a temporary file!**

**performance.js**

```
function sum_two(a,b) { 
    return a+b;
}

module.exports = { 
    sum_two,
}
```

**app.js:**

```
// 1.Store performance.js in the memory somehow  // HAPPENS ONLY ONCE!
// 2.run against the memory the function sum_two // HAPPENS OVER AND OVER AGAIN
const res = sum_two(1,2);
console.log('Result:' , res);
```

Comment: `import { sum_two } from "performance.js" ?` I'm not sure what you mean by "executing a script _in memory_". Node loads the whole application (JS files) in memory anyway. What makes you think it doesn't run in memory? If it doesn't, where do you think it runs from?

Comment: @JeremyThille: I don't want to have the code of `performance.js` on the disk , I want to have it in memory!

Comment: I get that. You didn't answer my questions. What makes you think it does NOT run in memory? Because as far as I'm concerned, it does.

Comment: @JeremyThille: If you remove `performance.js` the code will not run , since it doesn't exist on the disk.The question I'm asking is: Is it possible to put the script of `performance.js` in the memory once , and then run against it ?

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to me. That's how Node works. Your JS files are stored on the disk (because they have to be stored/written somewhere, right? Somewhere permanent where they don't disappear.) When you do `node app.js`, Node will read all necessary files from the disk, load them into volatile memory (RAM), and then execute the code. When you stop the Node process, files are unloaded from RAM but remain on the disk. I don't understand why 1. you believe the code is _not_ executed from the RAM, because it is, and 2. you want to delete the performance.js file?

Comment: @JeremyThille: It makes perfect sense , if you want to prevent from anyone access to your code , for example my clients.I have a piece of code that I do not want to exist on a disk , but straight in the memory whenever the application starts.Then , run against it.Makes perfect sense .... just think about it a little bit..

Comment: "Makes perfect sense" to you. Not to me. Now what makes you think users will have access to your source code? This is nonsense lol :) If you don't explicitely tell your Node.js application to READ the performance.js file on the hard disk, then explicitely send it to the client, then they will never be able to access it. You tell me to think about it, I have been developing all my apps with Node for 8 years, and you apparently for 3 hours, so please don't tell me to think because "it makes perfect sense". It does _not_ make sense. Nothing of what you believe in this thread does.

Comment: Don't worry, that's only the phase 1 of the Dunning–Kruger effect. It will pass lol

Answer (score 2):

Use [new vm.compileFunction(script)()](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vmcompilefunctioncode-params-options), [new Function(script)()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function) or [eval(script)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

```js
// Example with esbuild
esbuild.build(esbuildConfig).then(res => {
  res[0].outputFiles.map((f) => /\.m*js$/.test(f.path) && new vm.compileFunction(f.text)())
});
```